# Magic the gathering rules

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

If one of the spells I have can make the enemy sacrifice a plainswalker but i choose the plainswalker from the game and I do that to a general is not the general banned from the game forever?

Comment: Please try to put a little more effort into your questions - this one especially is quite hard to understand, and because of that, it's not easy to tell whether answers are useful either.

Comment: What card or cards are you describing? I agree with TheThirdMan, it's hard to understand what you're describing or what game mechanics would be involved here.

Comment: Start by using the proper names for things. There's no such thing as a "general" in MTG, and there's no such thing as being "banned from the game". (Banned cards are cards that would be allowed by a format except for the fact that they are explicitly banned from that format. This is obviously not what you're talking about.)

Answer (score 5):

Nope.  When a general/commander leaves the battlefield, it's owner may choose whether to return it to the command zone or let it go to wherever it would have gone otherwise (library/hand/graveyard/exile).

From the rules:

> 903.
>   9. If a commander would be 
>   exiled from anywhere or 
>   put into its owner’s 
>   hand, 
>   graveyard
>   , or 
>   library
>    from anywhere, 
>   its owner 
>   may put it into the command zone instead.
>    This replacement effect 
>   may apply more than on
>   ce to the same event. This is an exception to rule 614.5

Your question is a bit vague but clearly deals with this rule here and so I suspect that it answers your question.